# brackets in php templates

Tags: php

I have a script, and now it's the perfect time to have an option to change `theme` templates.

I was looking forward to store these files in `php` files, or html files. with `CSS` file. I looked over some codes and I found that they use brackets to refer to the variable.

Here's an example of a template block:

```
<div class='block_div'>
<center>{title}</center>
{content}
</div>
```

I know that I can use `PHP` vars usering `<?=$var;?>`. However, I think the one above is better, and I looked over the web to find anything about it but I couldn't.

My Question is how I can use these brackets in my php or html code. to let the user changing the template only not the code!

Comment: ...and your question is...?

Comment: My Question is how I can use these brackets in my php or html code. to let the user changing the template only not the `php` code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this question belongs to this site but to stackoverflow. Anyway, I'd tell you to take a look at any of the several templating libraries out there, for both PHP and JavaScript, such as:

- For PHP: [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), etc.
- For JavaScript: mustache.js, handlebars.js